# transient and steady-state response of first order system

Tags: linear-systems, z-transform

Considering this general 1st order transfer function

$$
H(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}
$$

How to find (analytically) the transient and steady-state responses?

With steady-state response I mean response to a sinusoid. I'm particularly interested in the case when $a=\pm1$.

Conceptually I have some difficulties grasping how to deal with the fact that the z-transform for a causal sinusoid only exists for $|z|>1$ ([explained here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35001/is-z-transform-of-sin-omega-0n-same-as-that-of-sin-omega-0nun)) and that for the case when $a=\pm1$ the z-transform does not converge for $|z|=1$. So the 'straight-forward' procedure of multiplying $H(z)$ with the z-transform of a causal sine and then inverse z-transform the result seems to not be possible/valid. I'm confused.

Edit:

simple example

```
fs = 48000;
f0 = 1000; 
T = 3/f0;
N = round(T*fs);
t = linspace(0,T,N);
x = sin(2*pi*f0*t);

bd = [1 0];
ad = [1 -1];
yi = filter(bd, ad, x);
figure;
plot(t,x,'b'); hold on;
plot(t,yi,'r')
```

[image: blue: input, red: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region of convergence (ROC) of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transforms of a step-modulated sinusoid

$$x[n]=\sin(\omega_0n)u[n]\tag{1}$$

is the region $|z|>1$. The ROC of the transfer function

$$H(z)=\frac{b_0+b_1z^{-1}}{1- z^{-1}}\tag{2}$$

also equals $|z|>1$ (assuming a causal system). Consequently, multiplying the two transforms doesn't pose any problem, and the result also converges for $|z|>1$.

As an example, let's compute the response $y[n]$ of the system $(2)$ to the input $(1)$. For the sake of simplicity we assume $b_0=1$ and $b_1=0$ in $(2)$. First, we compute the response to

$$\tilde{x}[n]=e^{j\omega_0n}u[n]\tag{3}$$

The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(3)$ is

$$\tilde{X}(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1}}\tag{4}$$

The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the response $\tilde{y}[n]$ is given by

$$\begin{align}\tilde{Y}(z)&=\tilde{X}(z)H(z)\\&=\frac{1}{1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}\\&=\frac{A}{1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1}}+\frac{A^*}{1-z^{-1}}\tag{5}\end{align}$$

with

$$A=\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega_0}}=H(e^{j\omega_0})\tag{6}$$

The inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(5)$ is

$$\tilde{y}[n]=H(e^{j\omega_0})e^{j\omega_0n}u[n]+H^*(e^{j\omega_0})u[n]\tag{7}$$

The response to the step-modulated sinusoid $(1)$ is easily obtained from $(7)$ by taking its imaginary part:

$$\begin{align}y[n]&=\textrm{Im}\big\{\tilde{y}[n]\big\}\\&=\big|H(e^{j\omega_0})\big|\sin\big(\omega_0n+\arg\left\{H(e^{j\omega_0})\right\}\big)u[n]\\&\qquad -\textrm{Im}\big\{H(e^{j\omega_0})\big\}u[n]\tag{8}\end{align}$$

The first term in $(8)$ is the steady-state response, and the second term is the transient response, which doesn't decay because of the system's pole at $z=1$.

So the output has a DC component due the imaginary part of $H(e^{j\omega_0})$. Note that this is no contradiction with the linearity of the system, because the input signal is not a single spectral line but it has a continuous spectrum extending down to DC due to the sinusoid being switched on at $n=0$. This DC value of the input's Fourier transform triggers the system's eigenfrequency, which is a DC component. Note that this always happens with LTI systems: the output may contain oscillations at frequencies that are only determined by the system, not by the input signal. However, unlike in the given example, usually these transients decay because most of the time we consider asymptotically stable systems.

I slightly modified your Matlab/Octave script and added the analytical result $(8)$ for comparison. The analytical result is identical (up to numerical accuracy) to the result obtained by filtering:

```
fs = 48000;
f0 = 1000; 
w0 = 2*pi*f0/fs;
N = 200;
n = 0:N-1;
x = sin(w0*n);

bd = [1 0];
ad = [1 -1];
yi = filter(bd, ad, x);
figure;
plot(n,x,'b'); hold on;
plot(n,yi,'r')

% analytical computation
A = 1 / ( 1 - exp( -1i*w0 ) );
y2 = abs(A) * sin( w0*n + angle(A) ) - imag(A);

plot(n,y2,'k.'), hold off
legend('input','response by filtering','response by analytical computation')
```

[image]

Comment: ah, so I should have focused on the Fourier transform instead of the z-transform. Is there any chance that you can explain/derive or provided a reference to the added pole expressions for $H_{-1}$ and $H_{1}$? Can one say that the delta function in the $H_{1}$ expression change the magnitude response but not the phase response? Would you call the systems $H_{-1}$ and $H_{1}$ linear? The reason for this question is that if $\sin\big(n\omega_0\big)$ is input to the $H_{1}$ system a DC offset is added so in some sense intuitively this conflicts with the notion of linearity..

Comment: your answer is really good and I'm going to accept it and upvote (although it seems I can't right now). I just need to digest your answer to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: also I'm a little confused about your expression (4). Would you call that the steady-state response? what is the transient response then?

Comment: Do you think it feasible to multiply the Fourier transform of a sine to the $H_1$ system and analytically inverse Fourier transform the result?

Comment: hmm, I'm a little bit confused. Does the system have a transient response? I will try to add a small Matlab snippet for the $H_1$ system (with $b_0=1$ and $b_1=0$) which illustrates that there is a DC offset added to the output for a sine input (I somehow hope that the transient response can explain this).

Comment: ahh, maybe I should have added that sine is applied at time 0..

Comment: I have added a simple example illustrating the DC offset

Comment: @bjarne: I've added stuff to my answer addressing the question of the DC offset.

Comment: wow, thanks. It is slightly surprising to me that if we have a black box with with the $H_1$ or $H_{-1}$ system but we don't know they are inside and we input a sine and observe the output we can't conclude existence of non-linearity. So seemingly a linear system is able to produce components to the output that one would no think is in the input. Can you add a line or two about the validity of your derivation with regards to existence of the z-transforms. The one-sided sine appears to be valid only for $|z|>1$ and $H_1$ only for $|a|<1$. So how is final result valid for $|z|=1$ and $|a|=1$?

Comment: Just to be sure, in you final expression would you then call $-\textrm{Im}\{A\}u[n]$ the transient response?

Comment: @bjarne: Note that at the output there are no higher harmonics; a non-linearity would produce them. Also note that a linear system can only "produce" components if there are poles on the unit circle (i.e., the system is only marginally stable), and the input excites those components (i.e., the Fourier transform of the input signal is non-zero at those frequencies). For $|a|=1$, $H(z)$ converges for $|z|>1$, just like the one-sided sine. And yes, the right-most term in the last equation is the transient response, which doesn't decay due to the pole on the unit circle.

Comment: I think my confusion is mostly about convergence for $|z|>1$. I thought that the unit circle had to be in the ROC for $H_1$ in order to come up with a valid derivation. Are we implicitly invoking analytic continuation or something in order to understand $H_1$ at $|z|=1$. So what is going on is that the step function contains a DC component which excites the pole at $z=1$ which then produces a DC component in the output because the transient doesn't decay..So for the special case of $H_{-1}$ with $fs/4$ frequency input sine starting at $n=0$ it would then look like a non-linearity, wouldn't it?

Comment: I mean, in the output we would then have both a fs/4 and a fs/2 tone where the fs/2 would look like a harmonic.

Comment: @bjarne: Yes, in that case you would get a non-decaying transient at $f_s/2$.

Comment: I see you updated your answer. It is a very very good answer. Unfortunately I can't vote on the answer, only accept it. I have two questions that bothers me. One is that the $\tilde{Y}(z)$  in your eq (5) has ROC $|z|>1$, what are the implications? I think it means that the Fourier transform of the responses $y[n]$ and $\tilde{y}[n]$ does not exist, right? because of the presence of the non-decaying transient but is there any other catch to be aware of when considering inputs and outputs for which the fourier transform does not exist?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence "This DC value of the input's Fourier transform triggers the system's eigenfunction, which is a DC component.". Can you comment on that? Isn't $e^{j\omega n}$ eigenfunction to any linear system?

Comment: @bjarne: I should've said *eigenfrequency*.

Comment: @bjarne: In this case, the Fourier transforms actually do exist because the poles are on the unit circle (and not outside). You just get Dirac impulses in the corresponding Fourier transforms.